# choose what column to include in select based on a second select statment

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

i have a third party program that uses a data base table to display user created (within the app) fields on the screen so i have a table named User_Created_Fields that looks like

```
TABLE         FIELD_NAME          GROUP     LABEL
products      charge1             1         First Charge
products      begin_date1         1         Begin Date
products      end_date1           1         End Date 
products      charge2             2         First Charge
products      begin_date2         2         Begin Date
products      end_date2           2         End Date
```

when the app sees this in the table it displays the following in the app

```
Group 1
First Charge   *text area for input*
Begin Date     *text area for input*
End Date       *text area for input*

----------

Group 2
First Charge  *text area for input* 
Begin Date     *text area for input*
End Date       *text area for input*
```

The app saves the data for these fields to the table and field name specified in the User_Created_Fields table so the PRODUCTS.charge1  and PRODUCTS.charge2 fields (and same for the corresponding date fields).

now i need to create a report that selects the values that are stored in the Products table but... since the fields will be added by users i need the columns selected to come from the Table and field_name columns in the User_Created_Fields table.

so the output would look like

`PRODUCTS.Begin_date, PRODUCTS.End_date, PRODUCTS.Charge1, User_Created_Fields.Group`

the query would look (very roughly) like

```
select  (select Table ||'.'||field_name  from User_Created_Fields where Label='First Charge' and Group= (select Group from User_created_fields where label ='First Charge') ) from Products
```

this is going into a crystal report so i can't just use sql to generate sql like i normally would. There may be a more crystal esq way to do this as well but i am unaware of what it is. this info is going to be combined with sales detail obviously but i left that part out for simplicitiy since this part is un-godly complicated enough. i am using crystal 11 and oracle 10

if you have read all of this you deserve a reward.... thank you.

Comment: I can get the select to run but... it always just returns the table name and field name as text... it won't actually execute the table and field name as part of a select

Comment: You can use a combination of dynamic sql,stored procedure and global temporary tables to achiece this ,for some reference you can check the below http://www.dbforums.com/crystal-reports/1634385-using-oracle-package-data-source-report.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Crystal Reports can access stored procedures instead of sql statments. So put your code for creating the sql statement in a stored procedure and use that as the source of data for the report.

You might have to determine a maximum number of columns to support and always return that number of columns in order to make crystal happy.

Comment: the number of columns can be changed by the end user. Guess i could add a high number and the report would be set for a while but, would be better if didn't have to